# Why is my Blender project rendering like this?

Tags: rendering, shaders

I'm not really sure whats going on with my project. This is how the project looks before [image: This is how the project looks before] and This is how it renders [image: This is how it renders]. This is my shadings [image: This is my shadings] and the only modifier i have on is solidify at 2m. I'm also unable to bake anything, it'll get to like 2% and stop. I have it on cycles.

Comment: Maybe try particle system hair instead of nodes? Your setup is not clear to me.

Comment: I see two issues here: 1) the hair particles are very different between viewport and render (the shading issue wouldn't be one if you didn't have the particles issue) and 2) the baking stopping at 2%. For issue 1, check your particles child settings, I bet that's a big one. For issue 2, it might come from having too many child particles making the whole simulation unstable. I would advise you to upload your .blend file on [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/) and [edit] your post to add the download link so that we can check directly what's going on and get you an adapted solution.

Comment: Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)